Scrapy crawl stack: cannot pickle 'module' object
I was following this tutorial and encountered this error while trying to run the code.
File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 160, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 357, in __init__
    super().__init__(settings)
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = self._get_spider_loader(settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 221, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 470, in frozencopy
    copy = self.copy()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 452, in copy
    return copy.deepcopy(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 271, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 231, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 231, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 271, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 231, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nawalnaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object

I understand that the module object cannot be deep copied since Python does not allow it, but I am confused on what I should change either within the source code or within scrapy's files themselves. If anyone could help me, that would be great!
EDIT: I narrowed down the problem to the offending code:
class MongoDBPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        )
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]


I am now wondering how to convert the module to an object that Python can deep copy.

why are you trying to deepcopy a module?

Some of your settings are wrong. I doubt the problem is in the provided pipeline code.
